# install imagick in xammp 1.8.3

Tags: php, image-processing, dll, imagick

I tried every article on installing imagick in xampp but non of them is worked. it is surprise to see that installing dll is not as simple as it normally suggest

i am trying imagick on xampp 1.8.3 but if any one have any idea to install imagick in xampp then please guide me

I am trying on

```
Windows 8 Pro  64-bit
XAMPP Version: 1.8.3
Control Panel Version: 3.2.1  [ Compiled: May 7th 2013 ]
```

firstly i installed [Binary Release](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) `Win32 dynamic at 16 bits-per-pixel` in `C:\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16`

then load this [dll](http://www.sk89q.com/downloads/imagick/2.3.0/API20090626-TS-VC6/php_imagick.dll) in `php\ext`
and lastly edit `extension=php_imagick.dll` in `php.ini`

now after restart windows i got this error

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll'
 - The specified procedure could not be found.
```

lastly all other dll files have PHP 5.5.9 version but i have not found any php_imagick.dll that have PHP version 5.5 .Even this dll is also 5.3 PHP version. is this work also

Please tell me why i am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

I believe that imagemagick also needs access to the `CORE_RL_*.dll` set which are located in the `C:\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16` directory that you installed into.

You have to add this folder into to your PATH for these to be found at runtime.

Its a bit messy and if anyone knows a better solution than adding this to the PATH I would love to know about it.

Try downloading your php_imagick.dll from here http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/